# QML vs QPainter Widget - что производительнее?

Tags: виджет, qt, c++, qml

Собираясь разрабатывать новое приложение (на C++ и Qt), столкнулся перед выбором: как реализовать интерфейс - на QML или сделать по старинке виджетами (будет виджет, наследованный от QPainter на котором будут отрисовываться объекты да скроллироваться, и еще несколько виджетов с различными текстовыми полями и кнопками). С QML у меня нет никакого опыта, поэтому на виджетах я сделаю интерфейс намного быстрее. Однако, может быть у QML есть какие-то плюсы по сравнению с традиционными виджетами? Так какие же? Что из них производительнее?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Вы пытаетесь сравнивать кислое с синим. Вот скажите мне, например, что производительнее - `XML` или `Frostbite 2`?
- `QML` - это удобный способ программировать виджеты, транзишны, разнообразные визуальные эффекты и стили оформления. Он парсится *как язык,* но в конечном счете отрисовывает то, что вы ему сообщили, [с помощью того же самого `QPainter'a:`](http://lists.qt.nokia.com/pipermail/qt-qml/2010-June/000464.html)

> `QML` builds directly upon `QGraphicsView,` which in turn **builds upon QPainter,** which in turn builds upon `QPaintEngine` (and the internal `QGraphicsSystem` classes), which have various hardware accelerated implementations.

- Утверждается, что любой случай сложной разметки и логики на `QML` можно проэмулировать, вручную создавая элементы на `QGraphicsView`, и, соответственно, получить абсолютно одинаковую производительность.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, что мне ответили на Хабре:

> Насчёт производительности — разница
> только на старте, когда грузится и
> парсится QML. Далее на его основе
> создаются обычные «плюсовые» объекты в
> памяти, так что во время исполнения
> разницы не будет. А если ваш QML не
> супер-дупер навороченный, то вы и во
> время загрузки разницы не ощутите.
> Плюсы у QML — более компактное, более
> читабельное описание интерфейса, а
> также тот факт, что тенденция развития
> Qt однозначно идёт к QML. В Qt5 вроде
> бы от нативных виджетов понемногу
> отходят (тут врать не буду, возможно
> неправ).

Comment: Интересно, чем это отличается от того, что написано выше :)